# Powershell get second folder in filepath

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell, I am trying to get the second folder in a filepath, after searching folders for a specific function. The issue seems to be when using split-item, i have differing levels of folder depths.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path d:\domains -Recurse *.php | Select-Object -Property FullName
```

So for example I am outputting:

> D:\domains\domain.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\single.php
>   D:\domains\domain.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\tag.php
>   D:\domains\domain.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\canonical.php
>   D:\domains\domain2.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\inc\custom-header.php
>   D:\domains\domain2.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\page-templates\front-page.php
>   D:\domains\domain2.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\page-templates\full-width.php
>   D:\domains\domain2.com\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\canonical.php

I just want to search for the name of the second folder (i.e. `domain.com/domain2.com`) and just output the unique entries.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Why exactly do you want just that folder? Will you **always** want the second folder? Or, will you **always** want D:\Domains\Domain2.com?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 1` to grab the second item in a pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path d:\domains |Select -First 1 -Skip 1 |Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.php |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

The `-Directory` switch for `Get-ChildItem` on the file system provider and the `-First` and `-Skip` parameters for `Select-Object` were introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

If you're using PowerShell v2, you could do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path @(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\domains |Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer})[1].FullName -Recurse *.php |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will this work with powershell 2, as I get:

PS D:\domains> Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path d:\domains |Select -First 1 -Skip 1 |Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.php |Select-
Object -ExpandProperty FullName
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.
At line:1 char:25
+ Get-ChildItem -Directory <<<<  -Path d:\domains |Select -First 1 -Skip 1 |Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.php |Select-Object
 -ExpandProperty FullName

Comment: @PabloR The `-Directory` switch was not added to `Get-ChildItem` until v3.  You can work around this by using `| Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` in the pipeline after the `Get-`

Comment: Pretty sure the `-First`, `-Last`, `-Skip` and `-SkipLast` parameters were introduced in v3 as well :-|

Comment: Ah the joys :D Thankyou for your help!

Any idea if this is possible using v2 then?

Comment: @PabloR updated the answer. That being said, you _really_ should upgrade to PowerShell 5.1 :-)

Comment: I know, unfortunately a mix of a few hundred boxes where PS is rarely used.

Sorry maybe I am being dim, but that gives me an error, should I be calling it in a different way?

Comment: Get-ChildItem : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:85
+ @(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\domains |Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer})[1] |Get-ChildItem <<<<  -Recurse *.php |Select-Obj
ect -ExpandProperty FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (domainname.com:PSObject) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingEx

Comment: Looks like I've blissfully forgotten the nightmare that was PowerShell 2.0 :-P

Comment: Sorry I feel bad asking continually, however I think that is just processing the first folder in the domains directory, doesnt look to recurse through them all?

Comment: @PabloR No, the second folder. Were you hoping to have it go through each subfolder in `domains` and then grab the second _result_ from each of those searches?

Comment: Hi, so d:\domains has x number of folders. I want it to recurse through those to any depth, find any that have .php files, then just return the folder name under d:\domains (so for example if d:\domains\domain2.com had .php files somewhere within it, it would print domain2.com